# AWS, steps for enabling HTTPS on a Windows EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, https

I'm very new to AWS, so if any of the info I give you is not correct, I would appreciate a correction.

I have a single EC2 instance, running Windows, and using Internet Information Services (IIS). That instance has an elastic IP address set, so anytime I want to access my web, I do it through "http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/myWeb/controller/view.

I have a mobile app that opens a webview through an address like the one before, to register a credit card, and the API i'm using for that is requesting to make the connection secure. Doing research, I found about AWS Certificate  Manager. It's of my uderstanding that you can only deploy a Certificate generated from the certificate manager to an ELB or CloudFront, but I don't have any of those.

All the documentation I read is fairly advanced for my understanding at this point or is focused on Linux servers, so I would like to know, how would you guys solve this? should I put ELB in front of my EC2 to be able to use Certificate Manager? or is there a better way to enable a HTTPS connection?

I also read about having to enable port 443 (HTTPS), is this an extra step I have to take, besides getting the SSL certificate?

Sorry if I'm all over the place. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options, host the SSL within the Instance, or use ELB/ALB to terminate SSL (and change port) and forward the connection to the Instance. In either case you would need a domain name registered (the trust relationship is against the domain name, not the IP address).

If you choose the AWS route:

- (Optional) Register the domain in Route 53, or transfer it in
- Register the certificate in ACM, or upload your own
- Create an ELB / ALB. Set it to use the custom domain and enable SSL.
- Create a 'listener' on the ELB / ALB listening on port 443 (IIRC the SSL is actually attached to this listener). Set the listener to forward all incoming connections to the Instance on a port of your choosing (e.g. 80 now that it is HTTP).
- If you are using websockets you would need to use an ALB (not ELB)
- Beware there is a monetary cost for using ELB / ALB.